# F# - assigning element in (jagged) 2d-array sets several elements

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, f#

I'm experiencing some behavior in f# that i do not understand. I was trying to create a 2d table using nested arrays. The sub-arrays will have the same length, so I could have used Array2D. However later on I will need the table rows as normal arrays, so in order to avoid conversion from a multidimensional to a regular array I want to represent the table as a jagged array.

The following code is an example of how I initialize and assign elements in the table.

```
let table = Array.create 3 (Array.zeroCreate<int> 2);;
table.[0].[0] <- 1;;
```

I would expect this piece of code to set the first element in the first row. However, what it actually does is setting the first element in ***all three rows***.

```
table;;
val it : int [] [] = [|[|1; 0|]; [|1; 0|]; [|1; 0|]|]
```

Why does `table.[0].[0]` set the first element in all three sub-arrays? I tried finding the memory addresses of the sub-arrays using `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement`, and it seems to me that they are different, so they three rows are not the same array. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `array.create`, it takes as an argument an object, not a function.

As a result, each element of the jagged array is a reference to the same array, so you get the observed behaviour.

Just use a function other than `array.create` to make the array